# How to define the same conversion and select the right one with TypeConverter in Room

Tags: android, android-room

In my dao I have this method:

```
@Query("SELECT category, group_concat(type) as types"  +
           "FROM Type" +
           "GROUP BY category")
public abstract LiveData<List<CategoryWithTypes>> getCategoriesWithTypes();
```

And this is the CategoryWithTypes class:

```
@Data
public class CategoryWithTypes {
    private String category;
    private ArrayList<String> types;
}
```

To convert the string that I obtain from `group_concat(type)` (that have ',' as delimitator), I want to use this `@TypeConverter`:

```
@TypeConverter
public static ArrayList<String> arrayfromString2(String value) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(value.split(",")));
}
```

The problem is that I already have this `@TypeConverter` that I use in another method in the dao:

```
 @TypeConverter
 public static ArrayList<String> arrayfromString(String value) {
     return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(value.split("/")));
 }
```

And obviously I get this error at compilation time:

```
error: Multiple methods define the same conversion.
```

There is no way to get around the error and use both `@TypeConverter` specifying which one to use based on the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer**: I think it's not possible.

**Solution that could work for you**:
Given you're creating the string with `group_concat`, a better approach will be to change your SQL sentence to this to set `group_concat` separator (instead of the default one ","):

```
@Query("SELECT category, group_concat(type, '/') as types"  +
           "FROM Type" +
           "GROUP BY category")
public abstract LiveData<List<CategoryWithTypes>> getCategoriesWithTypes();
```

and then using only this `TypeConverter`:

```
@TypeConverter
public static ArrayList<String> arrayfromString(String value) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(value.split("/")));
}
```

**Possible alternative**: using a character at the beginning of your `String` that defines your delimiter for this string, but in your case it will not work.

For example:

```
@TypeConverter
public static ArrayList<String> arrayfromString(String value) {
    if (value.length() == 0) {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    String delimiter = value.substring(0, 1);
    return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(value.substring(1).split(delimiter)));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunally, using group_concat(type) I can't set the first char as I want... maybe I can write ` delimeter = value.substring(0,1).equals("\") ? "\" : "," ` but it's very sad that there isn't a native option

Comment: Apparently `group_concat()` allows you to provide a different separator, if that will work for you. See https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat I'll update the answer.